# get file name without files extension using drag and drop vb.net

Tags: vb.net, filenames

I want to drag and drop a file on a button and store the files Name without extension to a text box. Help to get out of this problem. I am getting some errors on those codes.

```
Private Sub Button5_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)
   _Handles Button5.DragDrop
   Dim files() As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
   Dim file_name As String = Path.GetFileName(files(0))
   For Each path In files
        TextBox1.Text = (path)
   Next
   TextBox2.Text = files(0)
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) 
    _Handles Button5.DragEnter
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `i am getting some errors on those codes` this is not how to ask a question or get a good answer here.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] and spend some time formatting your code to look like code

Comment: [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel you missed setting AllowDrop feature to true
and also there is a function to get filename without extension "GetFileNameWithoutExtension"
Check the code Below

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button5.AllowDrop = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_DragDrop(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Button5.DragDrop
    Dim files() As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
    For Each indpath In files
        TextBox1.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(indpath) & vbNewLine & TextBox1.Text
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_DragEnter(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Button5.DragEnter
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```